# Select statement for birth date (extract day and month only)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need the Postgres query that shows all employee birth dates (showing only the month and the day, but not the year). What is the SELECT statement to do so?
birth_date is in employees
it's in this format: 1990-01-01
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the birth_date stored as a `date` or  as a string?

Comment: What you have tried? Please note that SO is not a free code (or in your case query) service. Show what you have tried and issues you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

you can format a `date` value using `to_char()`

```
select to_char(birthdate, 'mm-dd') 
from employees;
```